# ВершкОвий та вершковИй. У чому відмінність і чи є вона взагалі?

Tags: значення-слів, наголос

Коли ми приходимо у будь-який магазин, найчастіше просимо "вершкОвий" маргарин, масло тощо. Проте знайшла доволі двозначну інформацію:

> ***вершкОвий*** — прикм.; пов’язаний з мірою довжини: вершковий цвях;
>
> ***вершковИй*** — прикм.; виготовлений з вершків або вершинний: вершковЕ масло.

Таке трактування знайшла на сайті: https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru.
Спершу видалась мені ця інформація сумнівною, адже вона на російській мові і не є науковим виданням, однак ці визначення таки підкріплені посиланням на словники.
Проте Словник української мови в 11 томах все ж каже, що наголос спільний для усіх значень: "вершкОвий".

Чи є різниця у значеннях цього слова залежно від наголосу?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Цитована Вами словникова стаття — з [«Великого тлумачного словника сучасної української мови» 2010-х років В'ячеслава Бусела видавництва «Перун» (відомого також як ВТССУМ)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8). Офіційно частина прав на цей словник належать компанії ABBYY Lingvo і він публікується на сайті [ABBYY Lingvo Live](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9), але також його публікують інші сайти (зокрема [«Словопедія»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53394/837367.html) і вже згаданий Вами [academic.ru](//ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/16528)).

У свій час цей словник викликав шквал критики. Зокрема приводами для критики було те, що в нього війшов майже весь зміст [академічного «Словника української мови» в 11 томах (відомого також як СУМ-11) 1970-х років](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) (тобто плагіат), але без цитувань з літератури (а який сенс у тлумачному словнику без джерел?), а також велика кількість малозначних слів типу «баварський», «житомирський», «мюнхенський» тощо (але я не стверджую, що там лише плагіат і незначні слова, мабуть, укладниками словника все ж зроблена велика робота). Також критику викликала практика судового переслідування компанією ABBYY Lingvo інших сайтів-публікаторів (зокрема закритого нині slovnyk.net).

Я не знаю, звідки в ВТССУМі ці дані (про таке розрізнення значень за наголосом).

- СУМ-11 (на базі якого і зроблено наведену статтю з ВТССУМу), як Ви вже казали, [подає в усіх значеннях наголос -о-](http://sum.in.ua/s/vershkovyj).
- Сучасний нащадок СУМу-11 — [академічний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (відомий також як СУМ-20) 2010-х років](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) — [подає обидва наголоси, але без розрізнення значень за наголосом](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7661&page=282):

  > **ВЕРШКО́ВИ́Й**, о́ва́, о́ве́.
  >
  > 1. Прикм. до вершо́к 1. *Квітки брусниці — в тісних пониклих вершкових гронах, на коротких квітконіжках, невеликі, з білими або блідо-рожевими віночками* (з наук. літ.).
  > 2. Зробл. із вершків (див. вершки́ 1). *Смачна риба, як на вершковім маслі*
  >      (Остап Вишня); *Всюди багато продуктів, на майдані .. розпродують вершкове масло* (О. Гончар);
  >
  >    // Який має у своєму складі вершки. *Частування було сите, але не вишукане. Гаряче молоко, масний вершковий сир* (З. Тулуб); *Нічого зайвого! Тільки риба під вершковим соусом і біле вино* (із журн.).
  > 3. *заст*. Який довжиною дорівнює вершку (у 3 знач.). *Мало не вершковий, весь у чорних цятках, висячий ніс .. тримався на вусах-крилах, легких, білих, як комірець* (В. Земляк).
- Єдиний відомий мені інший словник, що подає розрізнення значень за наголосами — це [«Словник українсько-російський» А. Ніковського 1927 року](//archive.org/details/slovnikukrros), але [там значення/наголоси поставлені протилежно статті з ВТССУМу](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=8):

  > **Вершко́вий** — сливочный *[тобто від молочних вершків — примітка моя]*.
  >   **Вершкови́й** — вершковый *[тобто від заст. міри довжини вершок — примітка моя]*.

Comment: Дякую за детальнішу інформацію!